# Problema con una consulta de MySql

Tags: mysql

resulta que estoy intentando hacer una consulta en mi base de datos pero no me trae los datos que debería cuando la envió de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM gen_date WHERE gen_fh_rec BETWEEN 2022-05-10 AND 2022-05-13 AND gen_ciu_apli = 'Bogota' OR gen_fh_rec BETWEEN 2022-05-10 AND 2022-05-13 AND gen_ciu_apli = 'Bogota'
```

por defecto esta consulta solo me trae dos resultados que no tiene nada que ver con la condición, pero cuando la envió de está forma si me consulta como deberia:

```
SELECT * FROM `gen_date` WHERE `gen_fh_rec` BETWEEN '2022-05-10' AND '2022-05-13' AND `gen_ciu_apli` = 'Bogota' OR `gen_fh_rec` BETWEEN '2022-05-10' AND '2022-05-13' AND `gen_ciu_apli` = 'Bogota'
```

Que puede estar pasando ahí ya que necesito consultar unos datos desde el cliente y en efecto encontré este fallo en la query, agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Las fechas son cadenas, sino las escapas entonces estas realizando restas, es decir, `2022-05-10` es lo mismo que `2022 menos 5 menos 10 == 2007`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te han comentado tu error se debe a que te lo coje como una resta para solucionar ese error debes poner comillas simples pero no doble cuidado con eso.

```
SELECT * FROM gen_date WHERE gen_fh_rec BETWEEN '2022-05-10' AND '2022-05-13' AND gen_ciu_apli = 'Bogota' OR gen_fh_rec BETWEEN '2022-05-10' AND '2022-05-13' AND gen_ciu_apli = 'Bogota'
```